# Powershell's Out-File adds a newline to the Top of the file - Out-File vs. Set-Content

Tags: powershell, file-io

I have the following powershell:

```
# Find all .csproj files 
$csProjFiles = get-childitem ./ -include *.csproj -recurse 

# Remove the packages.config include from the csproj files.
$csProjFiles | foreach ($_) {(get-content $_) | 
             select-string -pattern '<None Include="packages.config" />' -notmatch | 
             Out-File $_ -force}
```

And it seems to work fine.  The line with the packages.config is not in the file after I run.

But after I run there is an extra newline at that **TOP** of the file.  (Not the bottom.)

I am confused as to how that is getting there.  **What can I do to get rid of the extra newline char that this generates at the top of the file?**

UPDATE:

I swapped out to a different way of doing this:

```
$csProjFiles | foreach ($_) {$currentFile = $_; (get-content $_) | 
               Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '<None Include="packages.config" />'} | 
               Set-Content $currentFile -force}
```

It works fine and does not have the extra line at the top of the file.  But I wouldn't mind knowing why the top example was adding the extra line.

Comment: IMHO `foreach ($_) {(get-content $_)` should/could be `foreach  {get-content $_ |...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[`Out-File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and redirection operators `>` / `>>`** take arbitrary input objects and convert them to string representations *as they would present in the console* - that is, **PowerShell's *default output formatting* is applied** - and sends those string representations to the output file.
  These string representations **often have leading and/or trailing newlines for *readability***.

  - See [`Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) to learn more.
- **[`Set-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)** is for input objects ***that are already strings* or *should be treated as strings***.

  - PowerShell calls `.psobject.ToString()` on all input objects to obtain the string representation, which in most cases defers to the underlying .NET type's `.ToString()` method.

The resulting representations are typically *not* the same, and it's important to know when to choose which cmdlet / operator.

Additionally, the **default *character encodings* differ**:

- **`Out-File` and `>` / `>>` default to UTF-16 LE**, which PowerShell calls `Unicode` in the context of the optional `-Encoding` parameter.
- **`Set-Content` defaults to your system's legacy "ANSI" code page** (a single-byte, extended-ASCII code page), which PowerShell calls `Default`.

  - Note that the [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) as of PSv5.1 mistakenly claim that the default is *ASCII*.<sup>[1]</sup>

To **change the encoding**:

- ***Ad-hoc* change**: Use the **`-Encoding` parameter** with `Out-File` or `Set-Content` to control the output character encoding explicitly.
  You cannot change the encoding used by `>` / `>>` *ad-hoc*, but see below.
- **[PSv3+]** **Changing the *default*** (use with caution): Use the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` mechanism (see [`Get-Help about_Parameters_DefaultValues`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx)), which enables setting *default values for parameters*:

  - **Changing the default encoding for `Out-File` also changes it for `>` / `>>` *in PSv5.1 or above***<sup>[2]</sup>.
    To change it to UTF-8, for instance, use:
    `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding']='UTF8'`
  - Note that **in PSv5.0 or below** you **cannot change what encoding `>` and `>>` use**.
  - **If you change the default for `Set-Content`, be sure to change it for `Add-Content` too**:
    `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Set-Content:Encoding'] = $PSDefaultParameterValues['Add-Content:Encoding'] ='UTF8'`
  - You can also use wildcard patterns to represent the cmdlet / advanced function name to apply the default parameter value to; for instance, if you used `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding']='UTF8'`, then *all* cmdlets that have an `-Encoding` parameter would default to that value, but that is ill-advised, because in some cmdlets the `-Encoding` refers to the *input* encoding.
  - There is no *single* shared prefix among cmdlets that write to files that allows you to **target *all output* cmdlets**, but you can define a pattern for each of the verbs:
    `$enc = 'UTF8; $PSDefaultParameterValues += @{ 'Out-*:Encoding'=$enc; 'Set-*:Encoding'=$enc; 'Add-*:Encoding'=$enc; 'Export-*:Encoding'=$enc }`
  - **Caveat**: `$PSDefaultParameterValues` is defined in the *global* scope, so any modifications you make to it take effect *globally*, and affect subsequent commands.
    To limit changes to a script / function's scope and its descendent scopes, use a *local* `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable, which you can either initialize to an *empty* hashtable to start from scratch (`$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{}`), or initialize to a *clone* of the global value (`$PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()`)

**Caveats**:

- Using the **`utf8` encoding in *Windows PowerShell* invariably creates UTF-8 files *with a BOM***. (Commendably, in *PowerShell [Core] v6+* it does *not*, and this edition even consistently *defaults* to BOM-less UTF-8; however, you can create a BOM on demand with `utf8BOM`.
- However, if you're running Windows 10 and you're willing to switch to BOM-less UTF-8 encoding *system-wide* - which can have side effects - even Windows PowerShell can be made to use BOM-less UTF-8 consistently - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65192064/45375).

---

In the case at hand, the output objects are `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` instances output by `Select-String`:

- Using default formatting, as happens with `Out-File`, they output an empty line above, and two empty lines below (with *multiple* instances printing in a contiguous block between a single set of the empty lines above and below).
- If you call `.psobject.ToString()` on them, as happens with `Set-File`, they evaluate to just the matching lines (with no origin-path prefix, given that input was provided via the *pipeline* rather than as filenames via the `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` *parameters*), with no leading or trailing empty lines.

That said, had you piped to `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line` or simply `| ForEach-Object Line` in order to explicitly output just the matching lines as *strings*, both `Out-File` and `Set-Content` would have yielded the same result (except for their default encoding).

---

P.S.: LotPing's observation is correct: You seem to be confusing the `foreach` *statement* with the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* (which, regrettably, is also known by built-in alias `foreach`, causing confusion).

The [`ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) doesn't need an explicit definition for `$_`: in the (implied `-Process`) script block you pass to it, `$_` is *automatically* defined to be the input object at hand.

Your `($_)` argument to `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) is effectively *ignored*: because it evaluates to `$null`: automatic variable `$_`, when used outside of special contexts - such as *script blocks* in the pipeline - effectively evaluates to `$null`, and putting `(...)` around it makes no difference, so you're effectively passing `$null`, which is ignored.

---

<sup>[1] Verify that `ASCII` is *not* the default as follows: `'0x{0:x}' -f $('ä' | Set-Content t.txt; $b=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PWD\t.txt")[0]; ri t.txt; $b)` yields `0xe4` on an en-US system, which is the Windows-1252 code point for `ä` (which coincides with the Unicode codepoint, but the output is a single-byte-encoded file with no BOM).

If you use `-Encoding ASCII` explicitly, you get `0x3f`, the code point for *literal* `?`, because that's what using `ASCII` converts all non-ASCII chars. to.</sup>

<sup>[2] PetSerAl found the [source-code location](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/02b5f357a20e6dee9f8e60e3adb9025be3c94490/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Operations/MiscOps.cs#L1032) that shows that `>` and `>>` are *effective* aliases for `Out-File [-Append]`, and he points out that redefining `Out-File` therefore also redefines `>` / `>>`; similarly, specifying a default encoding via `$PSDefaultParameterValues` for `Out-File` also takes effect for `>` / `>>`.

Windows PowerShell v5.1 is the minimum version that works this way..</sup>

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for his help.</sup>