# Random linebreaks in PowerShell standard error output

Tags: powershell, io-redirection, redirectstandardoutput, powershell-1.0, handbrake

I want to convert many .iso files to .mp4 with HandBrake, so I am trying to use the command line interface. I would prefer to write my scripts for this in powershell instead of batch files. However, the standard error contains linebreaks at random location if I use powershell.

For troubleshooting, I created a simplified script both in powershell and in batch.

Powershell:

```
& "$Env:ProgramFiles\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" @(
    '--input', 'V:\',
    '--title', '1', '--chapter', '1',
    '--start-at', 'duration:110', '--stop-at', 'duration:15',
    '--output', 'pmovie.mp4',
    '--format', 'av_mp4'
    ) > ".\pstd.txt" 2> ".\perr.txt"
```

Batch file:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" --input V:\ --title 1 --chapter 1 --start-at duration:110 --stop-at duration:15 --output ".\cmovie.mp4" --format av_mp4 > ".\cstd.txt" 2> ".\cerr.txt"
```

Both scripts create the same .mp4 file, the difference is only the standard error output they create:

Powershell:

```
HandBrakeCLI.exe : [10:41:44] hb_init: starting libhb thread
At C:\Test\phandbrake.ps1:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  "$Env:ProgramFiles\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" @(
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([10:41:44] hb_i...ng libhb thread 
   :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

[10:41:44] thread 541fc20 started ("libhb")
HandBrake 1.1.2 (2018090500) - MinGW x86_64 - https://handbrake.fr
8 CPUs detected

O
pening V:\...

[10:41:44] CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz

[10:41:44]  - Intel microarchitecture Sandy Bridge
[10:41:44]  - logical processor count: 8

[10:41:44] Intel Quick Sync Video support: no

[10:41:44] hb_scan: path=V:\, title_index=1

src/libbluray/disc/disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV\index.bdmv

src/libbluray/disc/disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV\BACKUP\index.bdmv

[10:41:44] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead

libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0

l
ibdvdnav: Unable to open device file V:\.
libdvdnav: vm: dvd_read_name failed
libdvdnav: DVD disk re
ports i
tself wi
th Region mask 0x
0000000
0. Reg
ions:
 1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8
```

Batch file:

```
[10:41:35] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[10:41:35] thread 5a2cc30 started ("libhb")
HandBrake 1.1.2 (2018090500) - MinGW x86_64 - https://handbrake.fr
8 CPUs detected
Opening V:\...
[10:41:35] CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
[10:41:35]  - Intel microarchitecture Sandy Bridge
[10:41:35]  - logical processor count: 8
[10:41:35] Intel Quick Sync Video support: no
[10:41:35] hb_scan: path=V:\, title_index=1
src/libbluray/disc/disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV\index.bdmv
src/libbluray/disc/disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV\BACKUP\index.bdmv
[10:41:35] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdnav: Unable to open device file V:\.
libdvdnav: vm: dvd_read_name failed
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x00000130
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
```

This bothers me because I would like to check these text files to be sure that there was no error during the encoding.

I suppose this may be related to a lack of synchronization between threads that write to the same stream but I am not sure about it.

**The question: What can I do to get the standard error output from PowerShell without these random line breaks?**

Comment: I've added a v1 tag to your question. Out of curiosity: How come you're (forced to) work with such an ancient version?

Comment: I am used to working with cmd batch file. I thought I will move on to PowerShell because I read that it is better. I am still learning it and I do not yet see the differences among the versions.

Comment: I see. While newer versions have remained backward-compatible, they also have bug fixes, new features, and performance improvements, so it is definitely worth going with the highest version available. v1 is practically extinct "in the wild", whereas v2 is (unfortunately) still around; current is v5.1. Note that there's now also PowerShell _Core_, a cross-platform edition built on .NET Core (current version is v6.1.0), which is the only edition that will see new features going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the `Start-Process` command, with `-RedirectStandardError`, 
`-RedirectStandardInput`, and `-Wait` options.

These `-Redirect...` options on `Start-Process` do OS level I/O redirection directly to the target file, as most shells do.   As I understand it, that's not how PowerShell angle-bracket redirection works, instead they the angle brackets pipe the output through another PowerShell pipeline, using `Write-File` (or something), which inserts line-breaks between strings it receives.

I'm not sure of the exact details of this, but I'm glad to hear it seems to address the problem for you as it has for me.

Comment: Thanks, using -RedirectStandardOutput and -RedirectStandardError made it work although I do not understand why this differs from > and 2>

Comment: @z32a7ul, you are welcome.   I've edited the answer with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that there is a certain width to the console, and the console itself is essentially being redirected to a file.

My solution to this is to redirect the output directly to the pipeline, using:

```
2>&1 #Interpreted by the console
2>&1 | x #Output directly to x
```

And then using `Out-File` with the available `-Width` parameter:

```
$(throw thisisnotsometthingyoucanthrowbutisinfactaverylongmessagethatdemonstratesmypoint) 2>&1 |
 Out-File "test.txt" -Width 10000
```

In this case, powershell will write 10,000 characters before wrapping the text.

However, you also have some odd line breaks in there that I can't replicate right now. That said, now that you know how to send output through the pipeline, you can use other methods to remove the line breaks.

For example, you can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356836/4868262) which prints out the exact control characters that cause line breaks.

```
$(throw error) 2>&1 | Out-String | Debug-String
```

Then, you can go through the output and replace the problem characters, like so:

```
$(throw error) 2>&1 | Out-String | % {$_ -replace "`r"} | Out-File "test.txt" -Width 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

[Burt Harris' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52694201/45375) shows you one way to avoid the problem, via `Start-Process`, which requires you to structure the command fundamentally differently, however.

If the output that an equivalent batch file produces is sufficient, there's an easier way: simply **call `cmd /c` and let `cmd` handle the output redirections**, as in your batch file:

```
cmd /c "`"`"$Env:ProgramFiles\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe`"`"" @(
    '--input', 'V:\',
    '--title', '1', '--chapter', '1',
    '--start-at', 'duration:110', '--stop-at', 'duration:15',
    '--output', 'pmovie.mp4',
    '--format', 'av_mp4'
    ) '> .\pstd.txt 2> .\perr.txt'
```

Note how the two *output redirections* are passed *as a single, quoted string*, to ensure that they are interpreted by `cmd.exe` rather than by PowerShell.

Also note the embedded escaped double quotes (`` `" ``) around the executable path to ensure that `cmd.exe` sees the entire path as a single, double-quoted string.

---

As for the extra line breaks you're seeing: 
I have no specific explanation, but I can tell you **how `>` and `2>` work differently in PowerShell** - both compared to `cmd.exe` (batch files) and `Start-Process` with `-RedirectStandard*`:

- `cmd.exe`'s redirection operator (`>`) writes raw bytes to the specified target file, both when redirecting stdout (just `>` or, explicitly, `1>`) and stderr (`2>`); as such, text output by external programs such as `HandBrakeCLI.exe` is passed through as-is.
- `Start-Process`, which uses the .NET API under the hood, does essentially the same when `-RedirectStandardOutput` and/or `-RedirectStandardError` parameters are specified.

By contrast, Powershell's own `>` operator functions differently:

- PowerShell-*internally* (when calling native PowerShell commands) it converts input *objects* (that aren't already *strings*) to *strings* using PowerShell's rich output formatting system, before sending them to the output file(s), using the character encoding detailed below.
- **Output received *from external programs* is assumed to be *text***, whose encoding is assumed to be the system's OEM character encoding by default, as reflected in `[console]::OutputEncoding` and `chcp`. The **decoded text is loaded into .NET strings** (which are inherently UTF-16-based) *line by line*.

  - For **redirected *stdout* output**, these strings are ***re-encoded* on output to the target file**, using the following encoding by default:

    - Windows PowerShell: UTF-16LE ("Unicode")
    - PowerShell Core: UTF-8 *without BOM*
    - Note: Only in Windows PowerShell v5.1 or higher and PowerShell Core can you change these defaults - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/45375) for details.
  - By contrast, **when redirecting *stderr* output**, via stream `2` (PowerShell's error stream), the strings are *wrapped in error objects* (instances of type `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`) before being output, and the resulting objects are converted to strings based on PowerShell's output-formatting system, and the same character encoding as above is applied on output to the target file.

    - You can see evidence of that in your output containing extra information and lines such as `HandBrakeCLI.exe : [10:41:44] hb_init: starting libhb thread` and 
      `At C:\Test\phandbrake.ps1:1 char:2`, ...
    - It also means that extra line breaks can be introduced, because text produced by the output-formatting system assumes a fixed line width based on the console window's width.
    - That said, that doesn't explain the oddly placed line breaks in your case.