# Powershell cmd /c with 2 pairs of quotes works on Win 7 but not Win 10

Tags: powershell, command-line

When I run this Powershell command, it works on my Windows 7 PC, but not on my Windows 10 PC, why is that?

```
cmd /c "`"`"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe`"`""
```

The error is

```
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The command

```
cmd /c "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe`""
```

works on both but I have to add another pair of quotes because my command actually contains paths:

```
cmd /c "`"`"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe`" `"$runner_File`" > `"$runnerResult_File`"`""
```

Comment: Remove the first set of escaped double quotes: ``cmd /c "`"C:\Prog...VIEW.exe`" `"$runner_File`" > `"$runnerResult_File`""``. Or remove the outer double quotes entirely and let PowerShell handle the output redirection: `cmd /c "C:\Prog...VIEW.exe" "$runner_File" > "$runnerResult_File"`.

Comment: That does not work as soon as `$runner_File` contains spaces.

Comment: Then add extra double quotes around that variable (need to escape those) or define the variable including the double quotes (`$runner_File = '"C:\path to\file"'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Avoid the quoting headaches**:

- by letting PowerShell handle the invocation of your console application *directly*
- and by emulating `cmd.exe`'s `>` redirection with `Set-Content -Encoding Oem`:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe" $runner_File |
  Set-Content -Encoding Oem $runnerResult_File
```

Read on for an explanation.

See the bottom section if you do want to solve the original problem with `cmd /c`.

---

- There is generally no need to use `cmd /c` to invoke console applications from PowerShell.

  - Piping to `Set-Content -Encoding Oem` can be used to emulate `cmd.exe`'s `>` output redirection, though note that this may slow things down.

    - On the plus side, `Set-Content` allows you to *control* the output encoding.
  - To control what character encoding PowerShell assumes the console application's output uses, set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` *before* invoking the application.
  - While you could use PowerShell's own `>`, it would create UTF-16LE files by default in Windows PowerShell (and BOM-less UTF-8 files in PowerShell *Core*) - though in PSv5.1+ you can [change the encoding that `>` uses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/45375) via the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` dictionary of presets.
- To invoke a console application whose path needs quoting or is provided via a variable, use `&`, the call operator.
- If you provide arguments via variables (e.g., `$runnerFile`), PowerShell will take care of quoting the variable values for you, behind the scenes, if needed.

---

**Solving the problem with `cmd /c`**:

Bizarrely, **passing a command line to `cmd /c` that contains *multiple* `"..."`-enclosed arguments *additionally* requires enclosing the *entire* command line in `"..."`**.

Here's how to achieve that from PowerShell, by:

- placing individually escaped `"` instances (`` `" ``) on both ends of the command line passed to `cmd /c`, which become the overall enclosing `"..."`.
- otherwise relying on PowerShell's own behind-the-scenes on-demand quoting of variable values.

```
cmd /c `" "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe" $runner_File > $runnerResult_File `"
```