# Convert BASH sed command for replacing strings in files to Powershell command

Tags: bash, powershell, sed

I am trying to create a Power Shell script that is replacing one string with another in all folder and sub-folder files also to print all the paths the script went through. So I have written the Bash command but can't convert it to Powershell command

Here is the bash command that is doing the job correctly

```
find ./ -print -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' {} \;
```

The closest I found was

```
ls * -rec | %{ $f=$_; (gc $f.PSPath) | %{ $_ -replace "string1", "string2" } | sc $f.PSPath }
```

But it looks like is not doing the job the same, plus it is not printing the path

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what the Bash script is supposed to do. Idiomatic Powershell with pipelines and objects is quite different from Bash approach in many cases.

Comment: Setting `$f=$_` doesn't output anything, insert `$f=$_;$f;...` or `foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse)){$File.FullName;(Get-Content $File) -replace "string1", "string2" | Set-Content $File }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple `ForEach-Object` loops. For implementing `-type f` you need to filter for files, though. In PowerShell v3 and newer you'd do that with the parameter `-File`. In earlier versions you'd have to add a `Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}` to the pipeline.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace 'string1', 'string2' |
        Set-Content $_.FullName
    $_.FullName
}
```

or (for short):

```
ls -r -File | %{(gc $_.FullName) -replace 'string1', 'string2' | sc $_.FullName; $_.FullName}
```

Note that `Set-Content` automatically saves the file with ASCII encoding (well, technically it's an ANSI encoding, but let's ignore that since Microsoft has the bad habit of using the two terms synonymous anyway), so you may need to specify a different encoding if you don't want that.

Note also that if you have non-text files you may want to exclude them from processing, since `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` do specific things when reading/writing files that are undesirable for binary files (`Get-Content` without the parameter `-Raw` or `-Encoding Byte` splits the input at newlines, `Set-Content` appends a newline (CR-LF) to the end of each input string before writing them to the output file).

Comment: `$_ | gc` is even shorter than `gc $_.FullName`. Also, converting FileInfo objects to string gives the `FullName`, so that technically `sc $_` and `gc $_` would be valid.

Comment: True for `$_ | gc`. But I wanted to retain at least some level of readability. This isn't Perl after all. ;) As for the auto-conversion: that depends on the context unfortunately. In some cases the `Name` property is expanded, and in others the `FullName` property, so using `$_.FullName` is usually the safer approach.

Comment: Yep, that was more of an FYI for the OP. The only gripe I have with the `gc` / `sc` approach is that it silently changes file encodings, which may blow up further down the line in subsequent processing.

Comment: it is weird cuz the command this way changes also the .png files, what is there to be changed?

Comment: As I  am noticing it is changing file content with file path ... I am trying the shorter version

Comment: @Merian For more details about how `Set-Content` handles output see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/1630171). TL;DR: you'll want to exclude binary files from text file processing.

Comment: Nitpicking: the `print all the paths the script went through` part is missing.

Comment: Added (sort of). However, that will only display the paths of the *files*, not those of folders. If they want to re-create the behavior of the `find` commandline *exactly* they'd need to enumerate/print everything (files and folders) and discriminate between files and folders only for the replacement operation.