# Write-Output with no BOM

Tags: powershell, utf-8, byte-order-mark

If I run a command like this:

```
Write-Output March > a.txt
```

I get this result:

```
        U+FEFF    
M       U+004D          
a       U+0061          
r       U+0072    
c       U+0063          
h       U+0068 
        U+000D       
\n      U+000A
```

I do not want the BOM. I tried different actions, like this:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
[Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)
```

but none of them seem to address the issue. Note I am using PowerShell 5.1. I
did see some similar questions, but not quite the same issue as this, as they
were dealing with piping and external commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only using ascii characters, set-content would be fine in powershell 5.1:

```
Write-Output March | set-content a.txt
'March' | set-content a.txt
```

Or set the default encoding of out-file to ascii in your $profile with this hashtable.  The default encoding of out-file is utf16 or 'unicode' encoding.  '>' is a shortcut for out-file.  The name of the key has to be quoted because it contains a colon.  utf8nobom isn't available until later powershell versions.  '>>' also invokes out-file and may mix encodings in the same file.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ 'out-file:encoding' = 'ascii' }
```

Then this will make an ascii file:

```
Write-Output March > a.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

**tl;dr**

- If you want *Windows PowerShell*'s `>` operator and cmdlets such as `Out-File` to output *BOM-less* UTF-8, your only option is to change to that encoding *system-wide* (**see caveats in next section**):

  - As a *one-time step*, run `intl.cpl` to open Control Panel's Region settings, switch to the `Administrative` tab, click the `Change system locale...` button and check `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`. Reboot required.
  - *Additionally*, run the following *in every session*, which is best done via your `$PROFILE` file:

    - `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'Default'`
- Otherwise, you must use .NET APIs directly - see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5596982/45375) - or write a PowerShell-friendly wrapper around them - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375), which also shows a `New-Item` alternative.
- Alternatively, you can install the cross-platform **[PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) edition**, which **consistently defaults to BOM-less UTF-8**.

---

**Starting with Windows 10, you can make Windows PowerShell *default consistently to BOM-less UTF-8* - assuming you're willing to change to this encoding *system-wide*:**

- **Change your system locale (language for non-Unicode programs) to BOM-less UTF-8**, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375):

  - In short: Run `intl.cpl` to open Control Panel's Region settings, switch to the `Administrative` tab, click the `Change system locale...` button and check the `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`; note that you need *administrative privileges* to make this change and that a *reboot is required* to make the change take effect.
  - **Caveats**:

    - This change **sets both the OEM and the ANSI code page to `65001`, i.e. (BOM-less) UTF-8**, which **affects not only *all console windows*, but *all legacy (non-Unicode) applications*, including GUI ones**.
    - As of Windows 11 version 22H2, this feature is *still in beta* and can break legacy console applications.
- Then, in Windows PowerShell v5.1, **add the following to your `$PROFILE`** file (this isn't necessary in PowerShell (Core) v6+):

  - `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'Default'`
  - `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false)`

With this in effect:

- All file-writing<sup>[1]</sup> Windows PowerShell cmdlets that have an `-Encoding` parameter will then default to BOM-less UTF-8 (`Default` represents the active ANSI code page, which will then be `65001`, i.e. BOM-less UTF-8) - notably including `>` / `Out-File` / `Set-Content`.
- Windows PowerShell then also *reads* BOM-less files as UTF-8, including *source code* and via [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content); normally, Windows PowerShell interprets BOM-less files based on the *system locale-appropriate ANSI* code page (whereas PowerShell (Core) v6+ assumes UTF-8).
- By virtue of the OEM code page then being BOM-less UTF-8 (as reflected in `chcp.com` reporting `65001`), PowerShell will also use BOM-less UTF-8:

  - When interpreting data received from the outside via its CLI.
  - When interpreting data received from an external program inside a PowerShell session.
  - The `$OutputEncoding` assignment above additionally ensures that PowerShell *sends* data to external programs as BOM-less UTF-8. (This preference variable fortunately now *defaults* to BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell [Core] v6+.)

Note that the above also makes all *PowerShell [Core] v6+* console windows use BOM-less UTF-8 in all respects, except that you don't need the `$PROFILE` additions (though they do no harm).

---

**Background information**:

- `> a.txt` is effectively the same as `| Out-File a.txt`.
- **Windows PowerShell's `>` / `>>` / [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) *default to UTF-16LE***  ("Unicode")<sup>[2]</sup>, which invariably uses a BOM.
- You have two **options for choosing a different encoding**:

  - Use `Out-File` *explicitly* and use its `-Encoding` parameter.
  - In v5.1 (and also in PowerShell [Core] v6+), you can set the default encoding for `>` / `>>` / `Out-File` via the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).
  - **However, in *Windows PowerShell*, the `utf8` value for `-Encoding`  is *invariably* a UTF-8 encoding *with BOM***, so - unless you're willing to switch to UTF-8 *system-wide*, as explained above - the only way to create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files is to *use .NET APIs directly*.

    - Note that in *PowerShell [Core] v6+* the `utf8` value accepted by an `-Encoding` parameter now (more sensibly) refers to a *BOM-less* UTF-8 encoding; if you *do* want a UTF-8 BOM there, use `utf8BOM` instead.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**The properties and variables you tried are related only to how PowerShell - in both editions - communicates *with external programs*:**

- `$OutputEncoding` determines the encoding PowerShell uses when sending data via the pipeline *to an external program* (which the latter can read via stdin (standard input).
- `[Console]::OutputEncoding` determines the encoding that PowerShell uses when interpreting output *received from an external program*.
- `[Console]::InputEncoding` is the encoding that PowerShell uses when *it* receives data *from the outside*, when its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) is called.

  - Caveat: You can't change this encoding from *within* your PowerShell session in this case, as that would be too late.
  - It must be set by the *caller*, *before* calling the PowerShell CLI, which from `cmd.exe` is most easily done with `chcp 65001` (see caveat re calling `chcp` from *inside* PowerShell below). While that invariably sets *both* `[Console]::InputEncoding` and `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, that is usually desirable.

Note:

- On Windows, `[Console]::OutputEncoding` and `[Console]::InputEncoding` by default reflect the encoding of the legacy system locale's OEM code page, as reported by `chcp.com`; on Unix-like platforms (PowerShell [Core] v6+), it is (virtually without exception, these days) *(BOM-less) UTF-8*
- Due to *caching* of the encodings in these .NET properties, you cannot use `chcp.com` from *inside* PowerShell to change these properties - instead, assign the desired encoding directly.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) for more information, which discusses how to make console windows on Windows use BOM-less UTF-8 consistently *with respect to external programs*.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, this preference is also applied to file-*reading* cmdlets, which is neither strictly necessary for BOM-less files nor does it do any harm for files *with* a BOM - even if that BOM indicates a UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoding - because a BOM alway overrides an `-Encoding` argument.</sup>

<sup>[2] Unfortunately, in Windows PowerShell the default encodings vary wildly across cmdlets - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).</sup>

Comment: Can system locale be set through cli or a group policy?

Comment: Also adding the two lines to the profile seems to trigger an addition of a 3rd line "値䑓晥畡瑬慐慲敭整噲污敵孳⨢䔺据摯湩≧⁝‽䐢晥畡瑬ഢ␊畏灴瑵湅潣楤杮㴠嬠祓瑳浥吮硥⹴呕㡆湅潣楤杮㩝渺睥⤨਍" (I have zero clue what it says) which causes Powershell to show an error every time I open it: https://imgur.com/a/c5Qfoz3

Comment: @gargoylebident, re CLI: I assume yes, via the registry; re GPO: not sure - but I encourage you to create a new question specifically for that. As for the  profile: sounds like an encoding mismatch, which you'd get if you added, say, UTF-8 or ANSI-encoded characters to a UTF-16LE ("Unicode") file.

Comment: Thanks, you were right as always. I was adding both strings using `| Out-File $PROFILE.AllUsersCurrentHost -Append` _after_ applying the system locale setting, and the profile file (the 5.1 one) is in UTF-16LE (as opposed to UTF-8 which Powershell now defaults to). Appending prior to changing the locale setting (or using 16LE when appending) solves this.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @gargoylebident. Note that for appending to existing files `Add-Content` is the best choice, because it tries to match the existing encoding. (If the file doesn't exist yet, it behaves like `Set-Content`, meaning it uses ANSI in Windows PowerShell, and BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell Core).