# How to create a utf-8 file using echo in batch script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I create a file in a batch script on a Windows Server 2012 r2. How can I make this a UTF-8 file?

```bash
echo MyString=Hello >> myconfig.env
```

It creates the file but it cannot be read by other application. If I open the file in Notepad++ it says the file is UCS-2 LE BOM.

The script is running as a part of a self-hosted Github action-runner, and I think it runs under Windows PowerShell.

I have tried to set the code page by using the following before the echo-script:

```bash
chcp 65001
```

and

```bash
chcp 1252
```

but none of these seem to make any difference.

I added `Write-Output $PSVersionTable` and got this:

Name                           Value

---

PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.19170
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

Comment: The question mentions only the command prompt interface but you've set the `powershell` tag. If there is an answer, it may heavily depend on PowerShell or not PowerShell. Please clarify your question.

Comment: In addition, if the question is about PowerShell be sure to indicate what version(s) of PowerShell, because encoding support has changed quite a bit between versions.

Comment: If the size of the file `myconfig.env` differs from 17 bytes, what is the actual file size?

Comment: @harper: The actual file is 310 characters long ( 4 lines )

Comment: "I think it runs under Windows PowerShell" -- does it or doesn't it? Throw in a `Write-Output $PSVersionTable` somewhere. Under `cmd` this will simply fail, under PowerShell it'll give you the version.

Comment: @MaxP The BOM is written before the first text characters. If there are additional lines, then the question doesn't show the relevant code. Look for the code that creates the first line.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I added the info to the question now.

Comment: OK, I have now found that there is a better way to write the file in Powershell, using `"MyString=Hello" | Add-content -Encoding UTF8 -Path myconfig.env`. Problem solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40098771/995714), [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5596982/995714), [Write-Output with no BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65191663/995714)

Answer (score 3):

">>" is shorthand for out-file, so setting the default encoding (utf8 with bom) (at least in powershell 5.1):

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{
  "Out-File:Encoding"={'utf8'}
}
echo MyString=Hello >> myconfig.env
```

```
Powershell 5.1:  utf8 means "utf8 with bom"  # "encoding signature"
Powershell   7:  utf8 means "utf8 no   bom"
```