# pentaho Kitchen exit code is not working correctly

Tags: powershell, pentaho-data-integration

I am executing my job via PowerShell script however the kitchen exit return code doesn't seem to work...
Based on documentation that I read below is the return codes for kitchen

- 0 = The job/transformation ran without a problem.
- 1 = An error occurred during processing.
- 2 = An unexpected error occurred during loading/running of the job/transformation. Basically, it can be an error in the XML format, an error in reading the file, or it can denote that there are problems with  the repository connection.
- 3 = Unable to connect to a database, open a file, or other
  initialization errors.
- 7 = The job/transformation couldn't be loaded from XML or the repository; basically, it could be that one of the plugins in the plugins/ folder is not written correctly or is incompatible.
- 8 = An error occurred while loading steps or plugins (an error in loading one of the plugins mostly).
- 9 = Command line usage printing.

  ```
   $FilePath = 'C:\pdi-ce-8.1.0.0-371\data-integration\kitchen.bat'
   $ArgumentList = '-file=C:\pdi_debug\debug.kjb -level=MINIMAL >> 
   C:\pdi_debug\bat.log'
   $PDIProcess = Start-Process -Filepath $FilePath -ArgumentList 
   $ArgumentList -Wait -PassThru
   Write-host "The Exit code from Kitchen is " $LastExitCode

   If($LastExitCode  -eq 0) #This doesn't seem to correctly get the exit 
    code we are wanting :-/
    {
     $EMAIL_SUBJECT='INT: Pentaho_J_load SUCCEEDED'
    }
   Else
    {
      $EMAIL_SUBJECT='INT: Pentaho_J_load FAILED'
  ```

Comment: Try `$PDIProcess.ExitCode` instead of `$LASTEXITCODE`

Comment: Yes already tried this but still no luck...

Answer (score 3):

- **To synchronously execute console applications or batch files and capture their output / check their exit code, call them *directly* (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`), do *not* use `Start-Process`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

  - When [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) *is* used, the *only* way to get the process exit code is via the process-information object (of type [`[System.Diagnostics.Process]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process))
    returned by the `-PassThru` switch and its `.ExitCode` property (with
    `-Wait`, this property is instantly accessible; without it,
    `.WaitForExit()` must be used, or polling of the `.HasExited`
    property).
  - By contrast, the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) is only ever set after *direct* invocation of an external program (by invoking it directly or - if the path needs quoting and/or involves variable references - via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)).

Therefore, **invoke your batch file *directly*, and check `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards**:

```sh
C:\pdi-ce-8.1.0.0-371\data-integration\kitchen.bat -file=C:\pdi_debug\debug.kjb -level=MINIMAL >> C:\pdi_debug\bat.log
```

Note: This will make *PowerShell* append to (`>>`) to file `C:\pdi_debug\bat.log`, which means that *invariably*<sup>[1]</sup> the following character encoding is used:

- in *Windows PowerShell*: "Unicode" (UTF-16LE)
- in *PowerShell (Core)* (v6+): BOM-less UTF-8

If you need `cmd.exe` to perform the appending, call the batch file via `cmd /c` instead:

```sh
cmd /c 'C:\pdi-ce-8.1.0.0-371\data-integration\kitchen.bat -file=C:\pdi_debug\debug.kjb -level=MINIMAL >> C:\pdi_debug\bat.log'
```

Note: Due to quirks in how `cmd.exe` relays exit codes set by batch files when called from outside `cmd.exe` the most robust way to invoke batch files is to use `cmd /c` *and* to append  `& exit` to the command string - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250528/45375).

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell versions 5.1 and above, it *is* possible to control the default encoding used by `>` / `>>`, albeit in a non-obvious way: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/45375).</sup>