# which stream does out-file record in powershell?

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

By Default, does out-file record stream 1 or stream 6?

If I have a command:

```
invoke-expression $cmd *>&1 | 
       out-file -encoding ASCII -Append FilePath $log
```

Which streams does out-file record to a file?

```
1   Success stream  PowerShell 2.0  Write-Output
2   Error stream    PowerShell 2.0  Write-Error
3   Warning stream  PowerShell 3.0  Write-Warning
4   Verbose stream  PowerShell 3.0  Write-Verbose
5   Debug stream    PowerShell 3.0  Write-Debug
6   Information stream  PowerShell 5.0  Write-Information
```

Is it just Stream 1? or Stream 6?  I get a little bit confused because most shells have only 1 and 2, and powershell adds 6 which is like 1?

Comment: Only stream 1 is piped to `Out-File`, but since you've merged the contents of streams 2 through 6 into stream 1 upstream, the contents from all 6 streams output by `Invoke-Expression` will end up being written to disk

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the *pipeline* (`|`) to provide input to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file).

**Only stream `1`, the *success* (data) output stream is sent through the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) by default.**
The conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic, from which you quote, documents all 6 PowerShell streams.

Optionally - as you have done - **you can *merge* other streams into stream `1`**, which causes their output to be included as well.

You can merge:

- *individual* streams by their number; e.g. `3>&1` merges the *warning* stream (`3`) into the success stream; *multiple* such redirections may be used.
- *all (other)* streams, represented by `*`, i.e. by using `*>&1`

**Since you are using `*>&1`, output from *all* streams is sent through the pipeline and therefore saved to the target file by `Out-File`**.

---

As an aside: **`>`**, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (along with `>>`), is an effective alias of `Out-File`, so **you can use it *alone* to save to a file** - assuming `Out-File`'s *default* character encoding is acceptable:<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
& { 'success'; Write-Warning 'warning' } *> allstreams.txt
```

Targeting files with `>` also allows you to **save individual streams to *separate* files**:

```sh
& { 'success'; Write-Warning 'warning' } > data.txt 3> warnings.txt
```

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell version 5.1 and above you can change `Out-File`'s default encoding in a manner that also takes effect for `>`, via the [preference variable `$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/45375).</sup>