# In Powershell, out-file doesn't redirect write-host from start-job and invoke-command

Tags: powershell

I distilled this from a larger script.  The problem I'm having is that the out-file doesn't work to save "sdfsdfad" to a file and instead prints to the console "sdfsdfad".

```
    $ErrorActionPrefence   = "Stop"

    $s1=@'
        for($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
            write-host "sdfsdfad"
        }

    '@

    $s1 > $env:userprofile\Documents\s1.ps1

    $sb = {
        $ErrorActionPreference   = "Stop"

        Set-PSDebug -Trace 0
    
        $alog = "$env:userprofile\Documents\a2.txt"
    
        $null > $alog    

        invoke-expression $env:userprofile\Documents\s1.ps1 | out-file -Append $alog
    }

    start-job -ScriptBlock $sb | Receive-job -wait

    Get-Content $env:userprofile\Documents\a2.txt
```

Console Output that is suppose to be in "~\Documents\a2.txt" instead:

```
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
sdfsdfad
```

Comment: `Write-Host` goes to the `Information Stream`. Redirect it to stdout if you want to capture it's output `6>&1 | Out-File ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Capture Write-Host output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937190/powershell-capture-write-host-output)

Answer (score 2):

- [Don't use `Write-Host` to output *data*](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) - use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) or, preferably,  [*implicit* output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).
- Don't use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) to call scripts and [avoid it in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) - use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), to call a command whose name or path is based on a variable or quoted.

In cases where you don't have control over a script that uses `Write-Host`, you can use `6>&1` to redirect that output to the success output stream in order to send it through the pipeline, so that `Out-File` saves it.
Note that this only works in PowerShell v5 and above.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50937428/45375) for more information about capturing `Write-Host` output, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69841646/45375) for information about redirection syntax such as `6>&1`.

Applied to your code (if you really must stick with `Write-Host`):

```sh
& $env:userprofile\Documents\s1.ps1 6>&1 | out-file -Append $alog
```

Or, more simply, given that `>>` is effectively an alias of `Out-File -Append`:

```sh
& $env:userprofile\Documents\s1.ps1 6>&1 >> $alog
```

Note:

- Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, the order of the redirections does *not* matter.
- You can merge *multiple* streams selectively into the success output stream, or simply target *all* streams (see below).

Or, even simpler, to catch *all* (`*`) output streams:

```sh
& $env:userprofile\Documents\s1.ps1 *>> $alog
```

Comment: I guess my bad on voting for closure due to duplicate answer, tho I do feel OP is hardly listening to the advice we're giving hehe

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, closing it as a duplicate would definitely have been an option. However, I wanted to call out the anti-patterns in the question explicitly (not least because the OP has misused `Invoke-Expression` before, at which time I only called it out in a  comment, which was ignored).